# JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK simply won't work

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, json

We've got two servers, a local development and a live server. Our local server runs PHP 5.4 and our live server runs PHP 5.5.3.

Our graph data isn't working, and after closer inspection, there are quotes in numeric data provided by json_encode(). Obviously the first port of call is to ensure JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is set as the second parameter. Problem is, that JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is set, and the data from json_encode() is correct on the dev server (no quotes on numeric data), but not the live (numeric data is quoted), so it appears that JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK isn't working. I've checked my logs, no clues there, I literally have no ideas at all. I've googled and googled, nothing.

Am I missing a PHP extension or something? All updates ARE installed, stumped. Code snippet below, although I can't see it being any help.

```
// Provides an array of objects, tested, data is fine here
$data = new graph_data();
$json_data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

//... Further down the application
echo $json_data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this now. If anyone else comes across this, its really simple to sort (I can't believe I didn't do this in the first instance!)

You need to have a package called 'php5-json' installed, using the usual command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Thanks
Ste.