# Nativescript converts long numbers - last 3 digits are changed to 000

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have some Http call to the API, which returns some data.
The data is as follows:

```
{
"id": 7728806673365567000,
"title": "Status Unknown"
}
```

And now, the problem is with ID, as in database, Id is like:
7728806673365567677
So, valid id has 677 as last 3 digits, but data returned from the API contains 000, so:

Valid:   7728806673365567677

Invalid: 7728806673365567000

I'm wondering what is the problem with this. Maybe it can work if ID will be a string not number ?

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: Now i see that data in backend is in fact a string :
"7728806673365567000"
But Http call changes this into Number ?

Comment: The issue is probably in the backend.

Comment: Hi, in the database - in phpmyadmin all looks ok, so it's very confusing. Why do you think that in phpmyadmin it looks ok but console.log  output shows something else ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: I added a php solution in the end

Comment: Hi, what solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with NativeScript. You may call it a limitation with JavaScript, you are exceededing the maximum safe integer limit supported by JavaScript. The result will be same if you try this in Browser environment too.

So as you already mentioned use String instead of Number, that should fix this issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But how to convert this to string to get valid number? Right now the response gives me NUMBER000 so if i will convert this to string i will get 'NUMBER000' right ? Or you suggesting to do this in backend first ?

Comment: Yes, you have to handle it in the backend. If you refer any REST APIs they will handle the IDs as string when they cross this limit.

Comment: HI, I've chencked backend, thw ID is a string : " 7728806673365567677" but Http call changes this to 7728806673365567677... Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: That must be something to do with your backend, Http call won't change anything. You may cross check the response with any REST client like POSTMAN, make sure it's returning string.

Answer (score 2):

base on

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

> 9007199254740991

```
var d=7728806673365567677 ;
```

> undefined

```
d.toString()
```

> "7728806673365567000"

```
typeof d
```

> "number"

```
Number.isSafeInteger(7728806673365567677 )
```

> false

Number.isSafeInteger(7728806673365567)

> true

so

```
var data = {
"id": 7728806673365567677,
"title": "Status Unknown"
};

data.id;
```

> "7728806673365567677"

and

```
var data = {
"id": "7728806673365567677",
"title": "Status Unknown"
};

data.id;
```

> 7728806673365567000

for example in [php (click to try the code)](https://www.tehplayground.com/uuA8nhm0lFv5Ituj)

```
$data= array(
    'id' => 7728806673365567677,
    'title' => 'Status Unknown',
);

echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

should solve this problem and return

```
{
"id": "7728806673365567677",
"title": "Status Unknown"
};
```

> you need to have a package called 'php5-json' installed

- [PHP: json_encode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [php - JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK simply won't work - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113355/json-numeric-check-simply-wont-work)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should threat that as a string. It is larger then the max. possible number in JS 2^53 - 1, or 9007199254740991.

Because of that its truncated, the numbers taken away replaced with zeros. I dont know where this specific behaviour comes from, but that seems to be happening.

See:
[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 1):

You can use, [BigInteger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) NPM Module to solve this, also you can use some parsers for this problem, see this,

[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719775/parsing-and-converting-exponential-values-to-decimal-in-javascript)